# While using collection in mybatis, is it able to use aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

I am playing around with mybatis and using the following code. I wonder if I can count how many records in **booking_records** using aggregate function. I have tried group by but it fails. Or I need to separate it into 2 SQL queries? Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="Hotel">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="chiName" column="chiName"/>
        <result property="engName" column="engName"/>
        <result property="telephone" column="telephone"/>

        <collection property="classes" column="id" ofType="Class" javaType="List">
            <result property="id" column="id"/>
            <result property="hotelId" column="hotelId"/>
            <result property="className" column="className"/>
            <result property="isActivate" column="isActivate"/>
            <result property="totalRoom" column="totalRoom"/>
            <result property="availableRoom" column="availableRoom"/>

            <collection property="bookingRecords" column="id" ofType="BookingRecord" javaType="List">
                <result property="id" column="id"/>
                <result property="userId" column="userId"/>
                <result property="classId" column="classId"/>
                <result property="date" column="date"/>
                <result property="isActivate" column="isActivate"/>
            </collection>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>


    <select id="filterHotel" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
        SELECT hotels.*, classes.*, COUNT(booking_records.*) FROM hotels
        LEFT JOIN classes ON (classes.hotelId = hotels.id)
        LEFT JOIN booking_records ON (classes.id = booking_records.classId)
        WHERE booking_records.date BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate}
        GROUP BY booking_records.classId
    </select>
```

The error is as follow

```
Error querying database.  
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM hotels\n LEFT JOIN classes ON (classes.hotelId = hotels.id)\n
```

Comment: There are some obvious errors in the SELECT statement i.e. 1) the `GROUP BY` clause may be incorrect 2) `COUNT(booking_records.*)` is invalid. It should be `COUNT(booking_records.id)` probably. You should use some MySQL client to verify you have the right SQL that returns the expected results before involving MyBatis.

Comment: And to answer your question, it's not possible to use aggregate function if you want to map each row of `booking_records` to `BookingRecord`. Besides, you can get the count by calling `hotel.getClass(i).getBookingRecords().size()`, can't you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and I will try the method you suggest. I didn't think abt it before. Thank you